# How do I add a saved high score system in HTML?

Tags: javascript

This question is different from the rest, I'm asking how to add high score system for HTML, but in javascript editor. I've searched YT, and dailymotion, everywhere, and even similar questions. I want to use local storage, though. I haven't added any guesses to the saving of the high score, so this is just my regular code without it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:7px solid #00aaff;
    background-color: #00aaff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
<br>

<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)"onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)"<p style="height:27px;width:815px">Click to Accelerate</button>
<div class="resetButton"></div>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('Owner: Landon Sturtevant')">Credits</button>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('Click OK to Continue')">Pause</button>
<button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('High Score is ' + highScore());">HighScore</button>
<script>
function highScore(score) {
   var saved = 0;
   try { saved = parseFloat(localStorage.highScore); } catch (e) { saved = 0; }
   if (!(typeof score === 'undefined')) {
      saved = score;
      localStorage.highScore = '' + score;
   }
   if (isNaN(saved)) {
      saved = 0;
      localStorage.highScore = '0';
   }
   return saved;
}
var myGamePiece;
var myBackground;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var gameSpeed = 1;

function startGame() {
    myBackground = new component(800, 380,"http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/29/297846/2789895-cool+space+backgrounds+desktop+hd+wallpaper.jpg", 0, 0, "image");
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 50, "http://images.tourismholdings.com/public/2016/02/56bd3c714ecc6.png", 35, 200, "image");
    myScore = new component("30px", "Algerian", "turquoise", 15, 30, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 800;
        this.canvas.height = 290;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
      this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0; 
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;   
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
        this.x, 
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
    }
    else if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }  
     this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x; 
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {

    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop()
            document.getElementsByClassName("resetButton")[0].innerHTML='<button onclick="location.reload();"<p style="height:27px;width:815px">Restart Game</button>';
            return;
        }
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 150;
        maxGap = 250;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, 0, "image"));
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, height + gap, "image"));
        gameSpeed = gameSpeed - 1;    
    }
    myBackground.newPos();   
    myBackground.update();
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += gameSpeed;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="Space Run                                                         SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();   
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<audio <embed loop="true" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_m545gt2gbp1r5da8vo1.mp3" />     
 </audio>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with localStorage is simple. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
function highScore(score) {
   var saved = 0;
   try { saved = parseFloat(localStorage.highScore); } catch (e) { saved = 0; }
   if (!(typeof score === 'undefined')) {
      try { score = parseFloat(score); } catch (e) { score = 0; }
      if (score>saved) {
        saved = score;
        localStorage.highScore = '' + score;
      }
   }
   if (isNaN(saved)) {
      saved = 0;
      localStorage.highScore = '0';
   }
   return saved;
}
```

Comment: Do you know where i can put it? It doesnt show up the highscore when i die.

Comment: It depends on how and when you want to display the value to the user. Just call this function and display the returned value however you see fit. Simple example: alert('High Score is ' + highScore());

Comment: I just want it to pop up after they die.

Comment: I added the high Score script under the accelerate button code, and i made the highscore pop-up on click. Only when i click it, usually right after i crash and die, it says High Score is NaN

Comment: localStorage stores everything as a String. I didn't put checks in my example here. I updated the code a bit to be closer to where it should be and correct the NaN error.

Comment: Its saying that save is not defined now.

Comment: There was a typo in my isNan(saved) code. It's now updated.

Comment: Thank you, but when i test my game, (go as far as i can), the highscore remains at zero.

Comment: You likely are not setting the high score. At the end of the game, pass the current score to the function -> highScore(500); -> If the current score is greater than the high score, then the high score will be updated. the function always returns the high score.

Comment: Okay, well, it only stays at whatever i set it to, like 50. This is the current button code: <button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('High Score is ' + highScore(50));">HighScore</button>

Comment: In your example, you are passing the value '50' every time. So it will always be '50.' I don't see where in your code that you are holding the current game score. I see the component where it is displayed, but not the variable you hold it in. Whatever variable you use to keep track of current game score is what you pass to the highScore function. for example: highScore(game.currentGameScore);

Comment: This is the entire highscore code then. <button <p style="height:27px;width:815px"<type="button"onclick="alert('High Score is ' + highScore(772));">HighScore</button>
<script>
function highScore(score) {
   var saved = 0;
   try { saved = parseFloat(localStorage.highScore); } catch (e) { saved = 0; }
   if (!(typeof score === 'undefined')) {
      saved = score;
      localStorage.highScore = '' + score;
   }
   if (isNaN(saved)) {
      saved = 0;
      localStorage.highScore = '0';
   }
   return saved;
}

Comment: I just dont know exactly where to put your recent code in it

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some validations and conversions to alleviate some errors. You would just add this function to the bottom of your scripts. Make sure to grab the updated code in my answer.

Comment: So i can delete the highscore code i already have, and paste the new code at the bottom of my script?

Comment: I added the new code to the place where the old one was, but theres still an error. Could you tell me what code i have to put where, just to make sure its not something i did, (which im convinced it is).

Comment: If its easier, could i use a session highscore? the highscore that deletes when they leave the tab, but it saves if they play again?

Comment: Please update the code in your question for more help. localStorage is the "session" that will carry across tabs and page visits until the user clears cache and settings in their browser - it's stored on the client.

Comment: I added my present code to the one in the question.

Comment: The problem I think is that you only have a button to show the high score. You haven't written the code to save the score at the end of a game. In fact, when I run your code, there is no game at the moment. It's just a canvas and some buttons. The code I've provided needs to be injected appropriately into the game code for it to work as intended.

Comment: My game is HTML, you'll need to paste it into and HTML player. It works for me.

Comment: If you could run it appropriately, could you just tell me the exact position of where to put your highscore code, and how to fix the button or whatever your previous comment had said about it.

Comment: point me to the line in your code where the game detects the "end game" scenario. My best guess with the code I've seen is in the this.crashWith function. At the end, if crash==true then call the highscore method and pass the current score to it. It's possible that the game isn't running for me because I'm accessing it on my work's internet, which has restrictions on what content I can access. So external resources may not load for me.